Group/Cluster Polars Dataframe by substring in string or string in substring
Given this Polars DataFrame:
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        "values": ["A", "B", "A--B", "C--A", "D"],           
    }
)

1, How can I group/cluster it so that 1,2 and 3 ends up in the same group?
2. Can I even achieve having 4 in the same group/cluster?

If you add a row with C--E, should it be clustered with 1,2,3,4?

Yes. The relationship between these values are very strong, so a match means that it belongs to the cluster with 100% confidence.

Do you really have FROM--TO strings representing graph edges? Or is this just an example?

It is just an example. The strings come from previous concatenation of multivalued fields.

@jqurious . your question got me curious, why would this be bad practice if it was the case? I am not used to working with graphs.

Are abcde and xyzaf to be clustered together because they share the character a? i.e. if any characters intersect - they are part of the same group? I asked because the given example makes it look like you only have -- delimited strings.

Assuming you want to merge groups based on the substrings (separated by --), this is unfortunately not straightforward. You can't vectorize this since a member of a group can link to another group that links to another, etc.
One option is to use graph theory to identify the connected components. You can do this with networkx and connected_components:
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df.with_columns(pl.col('values').str.split('--'))
                              .explode('values'), source='id', target='values')

S = set(df['id'])
mapper = {n: i for i, c in enumerate(nx.connected_components(G)) for n in c&S}
# {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 1}

out = df.group_by(pl.col('id').replace(mapper).alias('group')).agg(pl.all())

Output:
shape: (2, 3)
┌───────┬─────────────┬──────────────────────┐
│ group ┆ id          ┆ values               │
│ ---   ┆ ---         ┆ ---                  │
│ i64   ┆ list[i64]   ┆ list[str]            │
╞═══════╪═════════════╪══════════════════════╡
│ 0     ┆ [1, 2, … 4] ┆ ["A", "B", … "C--A"] │
│ 1     ┆ [5]         ┆ ["D"]                │
└───────┴─────────────┴──────────────────────┘

Graph:

